# PHP / MySQL / AJAX - Mixing data from different users' form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Two users (A and B), logged in the system (with it's own user/password) accessing the same form, but different networks.

*User A is editing/creating data to registry 01*
[image: User A is editing/creating data to registry 01]
*User B is editing/creating data to registry 02*
[image: User B is editing/creating data to registry 02]

When A and B send their form (AJAX prepares data and sends via POST to [save.php](https://codeshare.io/anknyE)) the page reloads, bringing updated data.

What occurs is that sometimes it brings data from user B to A user's form, and 'vice e versa'. It is not always the same data and it does not always happen.

[image: Form 1 after Users A and B POST their data]

**NOTE:** The same page has more than one form, that can be sent independently. The save.php receive in a variable, witch form was sent to process. But it never happened to mix data from different forms of the page. *I.e.: form.Name just change with form.Name.*

At first I suspected something involving the sessions, but reading about it, did not make much sense, as it also occurs among users who are not even on the same network.

If there is more parts of the code to help the analysis, I have no problem in sharing it.

- Can the problem be the sessions?
- Can it be some limitation of the server (shared host)?
- Or can it even be in the script save.php being used
  simultaneously?

I also suspected config.php (database access) because it uses only one user. But @IncredibleHat said it doesn't [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133179/php-mysql-ajax-mixing-registry-data-from-different-users#comment85271077_49133179).

Comment: Not sure. We'd need some code to inspect. We are as much in the dark as you are... ? Side note: It would ***not*** be the 'single user db connection'.

Comment: Are you using any sort of form edit tokenizing routines to protect certain fields from tampering? Are both users sharing any access token you may have created beyond PHPSESSID?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I would provide codes, no problem. Like I said, I just have no idea of what part of the code could help the analysis.

Comment: I'd definitely start with the save.php. As isn't that also the php that returns new data to reload parts of the page with?

Comment: "Are you using any sort of form edit tokenizing routines to protect certain fields from tampering?" I think not. What woud it be?
"Are both users sharing any access token you may have created beyond PHPSESSID?" We just have a simple user/password table in DB, verified by a common POST login form.

Comment: :/ ... its a crappy situation to be in, for sure. The last time I had something like this happening, was with IIS and TangoEnterprise. I've never seen it personally in apache/php... so this is a baffling one. It's like somehow when one user edits something, its pulling the wrong id in the form to do the saving (or ajax is sending the wrong ids). I wish I could suggest more.

Comment: Here's the save.php code and an exemple of the ajax script
[link](https://codeshare.io/anknyE)

Comment: And I'm wondering about the downvotes... what's wrong with my question? :/

Comment: I dont know the reason on the downvotes. I did glance over the code, but its in a different language which makes it difficult, and its very vrobose (doing so many updates per operation, instead of combined update queries). Nothing immediately jumped out of me though. It looked like you were using id's, and they came from ajax. I'm sorry, I just don't have the time to dig through more thoroughly as its a lot to absorb.

Comment: kind of need to explain "sometimes it brings data from another user POST", as that seems to be the crucial sentence in this wall of text, but it doesnt make sense

Comment: **2200 lines of code** is hardly considered as a [mcve], not gonna bother myself reading that file. Please read [ask]

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I updated the question. Hope it helps. If I can do something better, you just need to tell me.

Comment: Thank you @AlonEitan. I simplified the code (it is 5% from the original one now) and did a match to the example images data. Also translated it to english.

Comment: Maybe this is an ID conflict `dados.append('salvar', "userdata");` in js and `if($_POST['save'] == "userdata")` in php, so it's never set to zero and can have some weird value ?

Comment: @ekans Sorry, this mispelling came after script translation to english. But they are the same (I just updated code. Thank you). This variable just tells the save.php witch part of the script will run. I already have plans to update it with function calls, instead of if/else tests.